# Upgrading from Windows 7 Enterprise Edition to Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-7-upgrade

I have a desktop PC that has Windows 7 Enterprise Edition installed on it. In System Properties I can see there is an activated Product ID key.

I'd like to upgrade (for free) this version of Windows 7 to Windows 10 (any edition). I downloaded Media Creation Tool in order to do this, but it gives me the following message: "The language or edition of Windows currently installed on your PC isn't supported by this tool".

Is there any way around this? After spending a while Googling I can't seem to find a straight answer. I just need to know if I can upgrade this version of W7 to W10, or not.

Comment: See answer by Andre>>>>>>>>https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install-winpc/migrating-from-windows-7-enterprise-to-windows-10/82109531-9d1b-4f1b-b18f-17d72183418d

Comment: There is no free upgrade from Windows 7 Enterprise to Windows 10.  In order to upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise you will need to have a license to Windows 10 Enterprise.  Since you don't have an eligible Windows 7 you won't be able to upgrade to Windows 10 without that ISO.  The free upgrade eligibility period to Windows 10 expired 3 years ago.

Comment: Re Moab's comment, the same Andre says you can downgrade Enterprise to [a.n.other] using a Downgrader tool - that might free you up to then get the 'not intentionally but actually free' Win10 upgrade. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_install/downgrade-win-7-ultimate-to-win-7-professional/cfebbc77-683a-4d32-bf3a-e897619a82f7?auth=1 The tool link is no longer active, but I found it here - https://softfamous.com/windows-7-downgrade/ **I cannot vouch for any of this information, you will have to do it at your own risk** hence I can't post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The Media Creation link and download is for Windows 10 Pro and Home.

Windows 10 Enterprise requires an Enterprise download.

Example:   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-10-enterprise

You need to try the Enterprise Upgrade.

However it works, Windows 10 from Windows 7 and 8 Pro, Home still appears to be free. But I am not certain about Enterprise.  I don't think that upgrade is free.

Answer (score 1):

My Dell system also came installed with Windows 7 Enterprise (while I have an official hard copy of Ultimate). Running a the installer normally gave me the following message:

> The language or edition of the version of windows currently installed on your pc isn't supported by this tool

I found that upgrading for free is possible by doing the following:

- Download and run "as administrator": https://softfamous.com/windows-7-downgrade/
- Click the downgrade button
- **do not re-install windows** (for a proper downgrade, this is necessary, but we don't need that). At this moment, some registry keys are changed, but officially you're still on Windows 7 Enterprise.
- Download and run the [**Windows 10 installer**](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). It'll proceed now as normal. After upgrade, you'll be upgraded to Windows 10 Enterprise. License info (under Settings > Update & Security > Activation) will show "Windows is activated with a digital license". `slmgr` will show you have a valid license.

Alternatively, you can (probably) do this by hand just as easily by following [the registry changes explained in this post](https://systemcenterdudes.com/change-windows-edition-from-enterprise-to-professional/). I didn't try this, but it's likely the same as the downgrader executable does for you.

If your Enterprise license is part of a volume license, you should ask your company for a proper upgrade procedure instead, they'll probably get it as part of their subscription.

As of Feb 2022, the upgrade to Windows 10 is still free.